# How to create transaction reference number

Tags: php, e-commerce, uniqueidentifier

In my php application, when a transaction happens I create a unique reference for the transaction containing timestamp and customer email address e.g

```
201701071157customer@gmail.com
```

This feels a bit hacky and I'm wondering what is the right way to do this? I would prefer the reference number to not be human readable. I have tried encrypting it but it ended up being about 40 characters long.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you by any chance display this reference number to the user?  If so, i think it should be readable

Comment: @Akintunde007 Yes the customer is given this number. Is that common practice?

Comment: yes. But i am confused as to why you wish to send an encrypted reference number to the customer?

Comment: Doesn't necessarily need to be encrypted, but usually reference numbers contain random letters and numbers.